# CSRF protection in a Rest API

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, security, csrf

I have a problem with `CSRF` implementation in a `Symfony REST` project. I'm using `AngularJS`, a `AuthToken` cookie is stored using `NG $cookie` service, and sended to server in every request in a `X-Auth-Token header`, the problem do I really need to implement a `CSRF` protection?
Other question, if the answer was yes, how can I do that with `Symfony`? Because it store tokens in server sessions, which is not `RESTful`, what is the best method to implement a `Django` like `CSRF` system for example (I guess they store the `CSRF` token in a cookie and then compare it to the form input token?
Sorry for my bad english, thanks!

Comment: A CSRF token is used to ensure that a sketchy script or page can't send request to your site while your session is open, so you use a CSRF token to prove who you are who you say you are. If you are storing a token in your app and then sending that in every request then there is no need to use CSRF as you are proving who you are with your auth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need CSRF protection when an attacker (from his own application) can make a user of yours inadvertently issue a valid request to your application that changes server state.

In short this mostly means non-GET requests (unless GETs change stuff, which they should not) with cookie-based authentication, because cookies will get sent even if the request was made from another website.

If you have the access token (used for authentication) in a header, you need to add that to requests in the Angular app, and an attacker will not be able to do that, so you don't need CSRF protection.

In case of token based authentication where the token is sent as a cookie, it would need CSRF protection. That would essentially be the same as plain cookie auth in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest for your case is to use this bundle https://github.com/dunglas/DunglasAngularCsrfBundle which has been specifically made to handle your use case.

Basically how it works :

- The server app forges a XSRF-TOKEN, stores it in session and send it as a cookie to the Angular app
- The Angular app reads the cookie and set the X-XSRF-TOKEN for the future requests
- The server compares the X-XSRF- TOKEN at each request (using a request listener) with the value of the token stored in session

If the tokens doesn't match, the request fails.